# Angular won't show Observable userdataof type any in async task

Tags: angular, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, pipe, observable

My home.component.html wont show my userData:

```
<h1 class="display-4">Hello, {{ (userData | async)?.username }}</h1>
```

this is the call from home.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userData = this.userService.getUser();
  }
```

and this is the Service:

```
export class UserService {

  private userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
  user: Observable<Userdata>;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private afs: AngularFirestore ) { 

    this.userDoc = this.afs.doc<any>('users/'+ this.authService.getUserId());
    this.user = this.userDoc.valueChanges();

  }

  getUser(){
   return this.user
  }
```

Here is the Auth Service:

```
  constructor(public  afAuth:  AngularFireAuth, 
              public  router:  Router,
              private firestore: AngularFirestore) {  
                console.log("Constructor for Auth Service")               
                this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(userData => {
                  if (userData) {
                    this.router.navigate([''])
                    this.user = userData;
                      if(this.user.emailVerified == false){
                        this.user.sendEmailVerification()
                      }
                    }
                })
              }

  getUserId(){
    if(this.user){
      return this.user.uid;
    } else {
      return null;
    }

  }
```

but nothing is shown in the html:
[image: Home Component view]

This is what I get when I log the userdata in home component:
[image: Log in home component after service call]

Hope somebody can help

Comment: Share the code of AuthService.

Comment: Are you Using Firebase Firestore or Google Cloud Platform Firestore?

Comment: Hi I added the Auth Service

Comment: I user Firebase Firestore

Answer (score 0):

you can try print data in console

```
this.user = this.afs
  .collection<any>('users/'+ this.authService.getUserId())
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    tap(ref => console.log(ref)
  );
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Hint, Its printing nothing because the User uid is undefiened. How can i Properly return my user uid as a Doc from my AuthService ?

Comment: Hi I Just found out htat at the Componnent Settings when i call Authservice.getuserid() i can print the user id but in my home Component it prints null booth called in ngoninit. How can that be ?